# How to write something to sqlite database?

Tags: python, sqlite

I always got this error when I trying to run my python script:

> c.execute("INSERT INTO test (word) VALUES (?)", (word))
>   sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The
>   current statement uses 1, and there are 4 supplied.

Any idea what is the problem?

```
import itertools, time, sqlite3

def main():    
    try:
        print ("Still running, please wait...")
        start_time = time.time()

        con = sqlite3.connect("dictionary.db")
        c = con.cursor()
        c.execute("CREATE TABLE test (string char(10))")

        for word in itertools.imap(''.join, itertools.product('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789@&#!*', repeat=4)):
            c.execute("INSERT INTO test (word) VALUES (?)", (word))
            con.commit()

    finally:
        print ("Done! Check the txt file!\n")
        end_time = time.time()
        print "Processing time was: ", end_time - start_time

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO test (word) VALUES (?)", (word))
```

Into

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO test (word) VALUES (?)", (word,))
```

Explanation:

`(word)` is evaluated to simply `word` which is a string in your case.  `(word,)` is evaluated to a single-element tuple, which is what SQLite expects.

(Sqlite expects a tuple with as many elements as there are question marks in the statement.)